# Installing anaconda on macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, anaconda

I am trying to install anaconda on `macOS Big Sur`. To do that in anaconda website I just downloaded `64-Bit Command Line Installer (428 MB)` that is for macOS, but when I tried to install it I got the following error :

`[/home/anaconda3] >>>

PREFIX=/home/anaconda3
Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh: line 377: md5: command not found
WARNING: md5sum mismatch of tar archive
expected: ffe6c79627482cbbc073b4d7509bacb2
got:
Unpacking payload ...
Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh: line 411: /home/anaconda3/conda.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh: line 413: /home/anaconda3/conda.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

I think the error arises because I am trying to install anaconda package that is for `macOSX` not `macOS Big Sur`. Hw can I fix this poblem?

Comment: Before your question gets downvoted, maybe try the graphical installer? https://towardsdatascience.com/install-anaconda-on-macos-big-sur-9fbd7c4b6c24
I’ve also had issues running downloaded command line programs in Big Sur because of the security barriers. You have to allow each program in System Prefs after canceling the failed attempt...

Comment: But I am installing it on a remote server. I do not think I can install anaconda on a remote server using `graphical installer`, can I?

Comment: If the server is a Mac, you can do a screen sharing session with `vnc ` but I agree it would be nice to get a solution to your original question.